# ExpatError: junk after document element xml python error

Tags: python, xml

I have a project that needs to be conversion from xml to dict in python. I am using the xmltodict library however when I convert the xml to dict it raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 311, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
ExpatError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
```

my code is:

```
import xmltodict

xml = '<row dataType="TR" ID="3B6B408870BA7AC3E05381010A0A5849" agentCode="690001001001001" transferId="G87_AGIN160901115820S441XB" tradeNo="160831287638239" platformType="AGIN" playerName="mubuuvu2" transferType="IN" transferAmount="28" previousAmount="0" currentAmount="28" currency="CNY" exchangeRate="1" IP="0" flag="0" creationTime="2016-08-31 23:58:16" gameCode="" />\r\n<row dataType="TR" ID="3B6B408870BB7AC3E05381010A0A5849" agentCode="690001001001001" transferId="160831231227456_Hunter_Out" tradeNo="160831287639025" platformType="AGIN" playerName="zxh123" transferType="OUT" transferAmount="-50" previousAmount="50" currentAmount="0" currency="CNY" exchangeRate="1" IP="0" flag="0" creationTime="2016-08-31 23:58:18" gameCode="" />\r\n<row dataType="TR" ID="3B6B408870BC7AC3E05381010A0A5849" agentCode="690001001001001" transferId="160831231227452_Hunter_In" tradeNo="160831287639507" platformType="AGIN" playerName="qqq19qq32b" transferType="IN" transferAmount="71" previousAmount="0" currentAmount="71" currency="CNY" exchangeRate="1" IP="0" flag="0" creationTime="2016-08-31 23:58:19" gameCode="" />\r\n'

_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml, attr_prefix="")
```

I can't seem to find a way to fix it and I'm not used in xml, I'm used with JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a starting root tag in the beginning and an ending root tag in the end of the xml string, it should work.

```
    import xmltodict

    xml = 'xml string here'
    xml = '<root>'+xml+'</root>'
    _dict = xmltodict.parse(xml, attr_prefix="")
```

Basically, it's just missing the `<root>` tag.

Comment: Remove the spaces after the angular brackets < in both the tags though, it wasn't formatting it correctly, I am not sure why.

Comment: What happens is the "row" now has a parent of "root" in the dictionary,, is there a way to not have a new parent for row?

Comment: what's the 'xml string' for again? it will just be ovverriden

Comment: Yeah, now row has a parent element root. Well formed xml should have a single top element, but yours has a number of row elements which gives the Expaterror. So the adding of <root> solves that problem. If you want an output that won't contain dict, assign _dict['root'] to a variable and use that.

Comment: THANKS! That is what I'm looking for!